# Compiling Pytorch Models to CoreML so they run on the Apple ANE

Tags: ios, pytorch, coreml, onnx, torchvision

I benchmarked 2 different Resnet50 Models - the Apple CoreML model, available on the Apple website, and a pretrained Torchvision Resnet50 model which I converted using ONNX (Opset9) and CoreMLTools (iOS Version 13).

I tested both models on a brand new iPhone XR.

Inference Times:

1. **Apple Resnet50**: CPU Inference 100ms, GPU Inference 60ms, ANE Inference 15ms
2. **Torchvision Resnet50**: CPU Inference 100ms, GPU Inference 60ms, ANE Inference 60ms.

As you can see, the ANE Inference for the Apple version is 4x faster.

Memory Usage:

1. **Apple Resnet50**: 46 MB CPU, 92 MB GPU, 35 MB ANE
2. **Torchvision Resnet50**: 48 MB CPU, 91 MB GPU, 91 MB ANE

The Apple version uses 3x less memory than the Torchvision one.

I am concluding the Torchvision Model doesn't run on the ANE.

I was wondering if anyone knew how the Apple Repo models were compiled in order to run on the ANE? From the model description, the Apple Models were originally written in Keras, but as far as I know the Keras implementation isn't different from the Pytorch Torchvision one, so I am not sure where the difference comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: Open both models in [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron) to compare them side-by-side. My guess is that the ONNX -> Core ML model has many more layers in it than Apple's model.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the quick reply. The models look almost identical, apart from the fact the ONNX model has "addBroadcastable" while the Apple Model has "add" operator. I'm guessing the ANE doesn't know how to handle "addBroadcastable" so it throws it back to the GPU. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, I've found that "broadcastable" and "ND" layers don't always (ever?) work on the ANE. The solution is to edit your model with coremltools and replace the addBroadcastable layers with add layers. I added an example of how to do this to https://github.com/hollance/neural-engine

Comment: What about PyTorch's torchscript and mobile front-end for iOS? It should be your go to way currently, not ONNX

Comment: @SzymonMaszke are you sure? From my understanding doing it using Pytorch iOS would not take full advantage of the ANE..

Comment: @JonathanFuchs no, I'm not sure, from quick lookup it seems third party apps cannot use Neural Engine. Weren't Apple's models written from scratch in CoreML and only based on `keras` implementation? I can't find exact information either to be honest. Anyway, is ANE necessary in your case and torchscript won't fulfill your needs?